# unable to instal libcrypto.so.1.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I have downloaded Android SDK and trying to compile it, it shows me the following error,

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

To install this package on my Ubuntu 20, I ran following command, but it says "Unable to locate package libcrypto.so.1.0.0"

```
$ sudo  apt-get install libcrypto.so.1.0.0
[sudo] password for paras: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcrypto.so.1.0.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libcrypto.so.1.0.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libcrypto.so.1.0.0'
```

Could you please help me on same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "libssl1.0.0" package is not available in the default Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) and later versions. Ubuntu 20.04 and newer versions use OpenSSL 1.1.1 by default, and older versions like "libssl1.0.0" are not included in the official repositories.

Edit the source list `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to add the following line: `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main`

Then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0`

I got the above steps from
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261614/ubuntu-20-04-libssl-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d